# Triplicación de datos en tabla SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

estoy tratando de hacer 4 tablas que se relacionan entre si. En este caso estoy haciendo uno de los selects, que relaciona la tabla Dibujantes, con la tabla "Principales_Casas". Al principio el objetivo era relacionarla también con la tabla de "Escritor", pero me daba demasiados errores. La intención era que apareciesen en la misma columna dibujantes y escritores, pero no lo he conseguido (si alguien sabe como hacerlo agradecería mucho uno mano) La cuestión es que he intentado hacerlo solo con los dibujantes, y me ha salido bien, pero por alguna razón que no logro comprender, se me triplican los datos
¿Alguien tiene alguna solución a esto? Adjunto código y fotos.
[image: Las Tablas]

[image: La Tabla]

```
CREATE TABLE Dibujantes (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    Nombre TEXT,
    Nacionalidad TEXT,
    Gran_obra INTEGER,
    Casa_Principal INTEGER,
    Colabora_Con INTEGER);

INSERT INTO Dibujantes (Nombre,Nacionalidad,Gran_obra, Casa_Principal, Colabora_con) VALUES ("Stan Lee", "Americano", 3, 2,2);


INSERT INTO Dibujantes (Nombre,Nacionalidad,Gran_obra, Casa_Principal, colabora_con) VALUES ("Dave Gibbons", "Inglés", 1, 2, 1);


INSERT INTO Dibujantes (Nombre,Nacionalidad,Gran_obra, Casa_Principal) VALUES ("Sara Pichelli", "Italiana", 4, 1);

CREATE TABLE Escritor (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    Nombre TEXT,
    Nacionalidad TEXT,
    Gran_obra INTEGER,
    Casa_Principal INTEGER,
    Colabora_con INTEGER);

INSERT INTO Escritor (Nombre,Nacionalidad, Gran_obra, Casa_Principal, colabora_con) VALUES ("Alan Moore", "Inglés", 1, 2, 2);

INSERT INTO Escritor (Nombre, Nacionalidad, Gran_Obra, Casa_Principal, Colabora_con) VALUES("Steve Ditko", "Estadounidense", 3, 1,1 );

INSERT INTO Escritor (Nombre, Nacionalidad, Gran_Obra, Casa_Principal, Colabora_con) VALUES ("Brian Michael Bendis", "Estadounidense", 4,1,3);    

CREATE TABLE Principales_casas (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    Nombre TEXT,
    Fundador TEXT,
    Grandes_Títulos INTEGER);

INSERT INTO Principales_casas (Nombre, Fundador) VALUES ("Marvel", "Martin Goodman");
INSERT INTO Principales_casas (Nombre, Fundador) VALUES ("DC", "    Malcolm Wheeler-Nicholson");
INSERT INTO Principales_casas (Nombre, Fundador)
VALUES ("Vertigo", "Karen Berger"); 


CREATE TABLE Grandes_Obras (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    Nombre TEXT);

INSERT INTO Grandes_Obras (Nombre) VALUES ("Watchmen");
INSERT INTO Grandes_Obras (Nombre) VALUES ("Superman");
INSERT INTO Grandes_Obras (Nombre) VALUES ("The Amazing Spider-Man");
INSERT INTO Grandes_Obras (Nombre) VALUES ("Miles Morales");  

SELECT Dibujantes.Nombre, Dibujantes.Nacionalidad, Principales_casas.Nombre FROM Dibujantes, Escritor
JOIN Principales_casas
ON Dibujantes.Casa_Principal = Principales_casas.id;][1]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No se para que tienes la tabla escritor si no la utilizas.

Por las columnas que veo que utilizas la consulta debería quedar así.

```
SELECT Dibujantes.Nombre, Dibujantes.Nacionalidad, Principales_casas.Nombre FROM Dibujantes
JOIN Principales_casas
ON Dibujantes.Casa_Principal = Principales_casas.id
```

El resultado seria el siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: La tabla escritor está porque se usa en otra consulta anterior que he suprimido en el código para que la pregunta sea lo menos confusa posible. Igualmente Acabo de empezar en esto y son prácticas de bachillerato para los días de cuarentena. El no tener profesora entorpece mucho el aprendizaje de esta asignatura la verdad. Muchísimas gracias por la ayuda, se me había olvidado quitar la tabla escritor. Se te ocurre alguna manera de que también aparezcan los escritores en esa misma consulta pero sin duplicar las columnas, sino utilizando las mismas columnas? De nuevo muchas gracias por la ayuda!

Comment: Exactamente a que tabla quieres amarar escritor ya que puedes hacerlo por con los campos Nacionalidad,Gran_obra, Casa_Principal, colabora_con con  a las tablas de dibujantes y  principales casas.